# How do you print unicode text to an output file?

Tags: c++, file, unicode, output, ofstream

I'm writing a C++ program in Visual Studio for class. I am using certain Unicode characters within my program like:

╚, █, ╗, ╝, & ║

I have figured out how to print these characters onto the console properly but I have yet to find a way to output it to a file properly.

In Visual Studio, choosing [OEM United States - Codepage 437] encoding when saving the .cpp file allows it to display properly onto the console.

Now I just need a way to output these characters to a file without errors.
Hopefully someone knows how. Thank You!

Comment: Are there codes for these characters in Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

Create the file using a `wofstream`, which uses wide (`wchar_t`) characters instead of an `ofstream` (which uses `char`).